# change bootstrap div class with jquery button click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

when page loading i want to show 2 col-md-6 div and one button saying "click to show third div". if someone click the button, i want to toggle third div col-md-4 and change previous 2 col-md-6 to col-md-4. Change button to "click to hide 3 rd div"

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<div class="row pull-right" style="margin-bottom:10px;"> <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btncontrol">Click to Add </button> </div>
<div style="clear:both">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="col_fld_6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="col_fld_62" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#E6B2A4;display:none" id="last_div">.col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML?

Comment: <div class="container">
  
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  
  <div class="row pull-right" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btncontrol">Click to Add </button>
  </div>
  
  <div style="clear:both">
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="col_fld_6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="col_fld_62" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:#E6B2A4;display:none" id="last_div">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
  
</div>

Comment: i ma confused how to write jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use add and removeClass

```
$('#btncontrol').click(function(){
  $('div[id^="col_fld"]').removeClass('col-sm-6').addClass('col-sm-4');
  $('#last_div').show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1boyw5oe/

or :

```
$('#btncontrol').click(function(){
  $('div[id^="col_fld"]').toggleClass('col-sm-6').toggleClass('col-sm-4');
  $('#last_div').toggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1boyw5oe/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well following is the HTML and JS you need.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rn4qsfww/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="row all-three-div">
    <div class="col-md-6">Div 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Div 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="display:none;">Div 3</div>
</div>

<button id="showThirdDiv">Click to show third Div</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#showThirdDiv').click(function(){
        jQuery('.all-three-div div').removeClass('col-md-6').addClass('col-md-4').show();
    });
});
```

You need to add a class `all-three-div` in three divs' parent div.